# Ruby: Method not returning expected output

Tags: arrays, ruby, class

I am trying to create a program which simulates a check out at a shop. However my `AddItem` method returns the class variable `@item` rather than just the singular item that it has found. So that once all the items have been added it will be able to display the total amount of those items.

```
class Action
  def initialize(customerMoney)
    @money = customerMoney
    @item = [{ name: :milk, price: 2.99 }, { name: :eggs, price: 1.50 }, { name: :bread, price: 2.00 }]
  end

  def CheckPrice(item)
    @item.each do |x|
      return x[:price] if x[:name] == item
    end
  end

  def AddItem(item)
    i = 0
    @item.each do |x|
      if x[:name] == item
        x
      end
    end
  end

  def CheckTotal(basket)
    total = 0
    basket.each do |x|
      total += x[:price]
    end
    puts total
  end
end

myBasket = []
customer = Action.new(20)
myBasket.append(customer.AddItem(:bread))

p myBasket
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use the [find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) method:

```
def AddItem(item)
  @item.find{ |x| x[:name] == item }
end
```

**UPDATE**

In ruby, `snake_case` is preferred. I've edited the code with the ruby methods.

```
class Action
  def initialize(customer_money)
    @money = customer_money
    @items = [{ name: :milk, price: 2.99 }, { name: :eggs, price: 1.50 }, { name: :bread, price: 2.00 }]
  end

  def check_price(item)
    @items.find{ |x| x[:name] == :bread }[:price]
  end

  def add_item(item)
    @items.find{ |x| x[:name] == item }
  end

  def check_total(basket)
    puts basket.sum{ |x| x[:price] }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby always returns result of the expression evaluated in a method. In case of `AddItem` it's `each`. `Enumerable#each` returns the whole collection that was under enumeration. You need to add a found element as a last line of the method:

```
   def AddItem(item)
       i = 0 
       found = nil
       @item.each do |x|
           if x[:name] == item
               found = x
           end
       end
       found # <<<<<<<<< returning found
   end
```

Btw. in ruby methods are named with `snake_case` not `CamelCase`. Also `@item` is an instance (not class) variable.

Btw you could do the  same with `find`:

```
   def AddItem(item)
     @item.find do |x|
       x[:name] == item
     end  
   end
```

as `find` returns the array element for what the block returns a truthy value

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, the last variable defined in a method is automatically returned. Since you are defining `@item` last that's what you are getting back. The problem is you are looping through `@item` but not doing anything with the result so `@item` remains unchanged.

Assuming the `@item` should actually be plural `@items`?, I imagine what you actually want to do is use select rather than each.

```
def AddItem(item)
  @items.select {|x| x[:name] === item}
end
```

This will return an array of items that returned true from `x[:name] === item`

Then again the name of the method `AddItem` doesn't truly represent what the method is actually doing, but thats another story :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not *explicitly* `return` something from a method (or `next` something from a block), then the *last expression evaluated* becomes the return value of the method (block, lambda, module definition body, class definition body).

Since you *don't* explicitly `return` from `AddItem`, the last expression that is evaluated will be the return value. The last expression that is evaluated, is:

```rb
@item.each do |x|
  if x[:name] == item
    x
  end
end
```

In other words, the return value of `AddItem` will be the return value of `@item.each`. According to [the documentation of `Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each), the return value is simply the `Array` that `each` was called on. (Note that this is actually not specific to `Array#each`, it is the *general contract* of `each`, so this is true for *all* implementations of `each`.)

This makes sense: the purpose of `each` is to execute a side-effect for each element of the collection. It doesn't really *have* a useful return value. So, the two sensible return values would be `nil` and `self`, and the library designers chose `self`. (Presumably, to allow for method chaining, I don't know.)

The next problem is that your block doesn't actually do anything. Remember, the purpose of `each` is to execute a side-effect for every element, but your block doesn't have any side-effects! If you wanted to do anything useful, you would need a side-effect (such as modifying an outer variable binding):

```rb
def AddItem(item)
  return_value = nil

  @item.each do |el|
    return_value = el if el[:name] == item
  end

  return_value
end
```

Alternatively, you could `return` the found item directly:

```rb
def AddItem(item)
  @item.each do |el|
    return el if el[:name] == item
  end
end
```

But really, what you want to do is find the first matching item:

```rb
def AddItem(item)
  @item.find {|el| el[:name] == item }
end
```

Note that there a lot of confusing things about your code:

- You have two methods that are both named `CheckSomething`, but the two methods do completely different things.
- Also, neither of the two methods actually checks something, one method prints something and the other finds something.
- Your method `AddItem` does exactly the same thing as `CheckPrice`, but it is named completely different. Also, it does things in a completely different way. (Which is why it doesn't work.)
- Again, naming: `AddItem` doesn't actually add anything.
- Also, what is that `i = 0` doing in `AddItem`?
- The class is named `Action`, which is a very generic name and doesn't tell much about what it's doing.
- It doesn't seem to do much of an action, though.
- When you instantiate `Action`, you assign it to a variable named `customer`. However, it doesn't appear that it doesn't do much "customery" things either.
- In the end, you put the customer into a basket. Just imagine, this were a real-world supermarket. Is that how it works in the real world?

And one last remark: the standard Ruby Community Coding Style is to use `snake_case` for methods, local variables, instance variables, class variables, and global variables. `PascalCase` is for constants that point to classes or modules, `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for other constants. We don't use `camelCase`.